# How to kill process using webcam, or remount webcam

Tags: opencv, webcam, opencv3.0, mount, zombie-process

I'm starting to learn how to interact with my webcam for image processing, but occasionally run into a problem when the camera is unavailable. When this happens, `opencv2.VideoCapture` freezes, or times out (if I use a thread with a timeout value to call it).

When this happens, the only way for me to run the code I'm working with is to reboot my computer. There must be some way to either find the zombie process using the camera and killing it, or to remount the camera, but I don't know what it is.

Comment: Solution is `ps -alx | grep <my username.` and then look for the python process I started an all of ts children